# Show single statistics in Grafana table

Tags: grafana, prometheus

Using the Prometheus plugin, is it possible to show single statistics in a table **as key:value table rows** in stead of time series?

This means the `current_value` only.

E.g. `node_uname_info` giving:

```
key     | value
------- |-------
machine | x86_64
nodename| ServerName
release | 4.10.51-1-amd64
sysname | Linux
version | #1 SMP Debian 4.10.51-1
```

Preferably I want to manually select one value per table row from different sources. E.g.:

```
A: node_uname_info.release
B: node_uname_info.version
C: "Some Manual String"
D: node_memory_MemTotal
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Grafana 4.3, indeed you can:

http://docs.grafana.org/guides/whats-new-in-v4-3/#prometheus-table-data-column-per-label

But column C in your example, containing `Some Random String`, will be hard to accomplish in Grafana. Consider using Prometheus [relabeling](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config) to permanently add additional data to you metrics in Prometheus.

Comment: Hi @remeika thank you for thinking with me. This example is still time-based. What I am looking for is key-value pairs per row. So two columns. One key, one value.